# Cannot extract zip file in php, no feedbackor error

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am retrieving my google map in a kmz format like this:

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp/map.kmz', file_get_contents('https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zLucZBnh_ipg.kS906psI1W9k') );

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp/map.kmz');
if ($res === true)
{
    trace("Number of files: $res->numFiles".PHP_EOL);
    for( $i = 0; $i < $res->numFiles; $i++ )
    { 
        $stat = $res->statIndex( $i ); 
        print_r( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL ); 
    }
}
```

But no files are showing and `$zip->extractTo()` is not working either. The file is downloaded on the server and I can extract it manually though. I have tried renaming the file to .zip or .kmz, still not working. I have opened the map.kmz file in Winrar and it does indeed say that it is a zip file format.

Any idea why it's not working? Do I need some special permissions to read the number of files or extract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got tired of the damn class not working, tried this method instead and it works:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zLucZBnh_ipg.kS906psI1W9k");
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp/kmz_temp', $data);
ob_start();
passthru("unzip -p {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/temp/kmz_temp");
$xml_data = ob_get_clean();
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $xml_data;
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your file types `.mkz` and `.kmz`.

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp/map.mkz',      
file_get_contents('https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?  mid=zLucZBnh_ipg.kS906psI1W9k') );

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp/map.kmz');
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a type error, I changed from zip to kmz in my question but that's not the problem, otherwise it would never get in the "IF" block anyways

Comment: Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your file and see what you get.